# jQuery show hide multiple links

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have 3 show more links in my layout. They must trigger all the same table with content. So when you click on link 1 it shows the table, but if you click on link 2 the table won't be hidden again (only when I click 2 times).

How can I fix this?

My code I have now:

```
$(".starterlink").toggle(
    function(){ $(".starterinfo").fadeIn('fast'); }, 
    function(){ $(".starterinfo").fadeOut('fast'); }
);
```

Comment: I wanna show and hide a table with info inside it. But the table can be triggered by 3 separated links on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, why don't you do something like:

```
$(".starterlink").click( function(){ $(".starterinfo").fadeToggle('fast'); } );
```

Updated:

The following test code works fine for me.

```
<a href="#" class="starterlink">Click me</a>
<div class="starterinfo">This will fade in and out</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".starterlink").click(function () { $(".starterinfo").fadeToggle('fast'); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`toggle()` function has no `toggle(function, function)` signature. IE it doesn't take two functions as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
$("#link1").click(function(){
    $("#tableid").attr('visible', false);
});

$("#link2").click(function(){
    $("#tableid").attr('visible', true);
});
```